# How to merge SaveChanges and multiple SQL commands into a single sp_executesql in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following code inside my DbContext class:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {    
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Schema1.View ([Key],[Value]) VALUES('Flag', '1')"); //session #1?
        base.SaveChanges(); //session #2? :(
    }
}
```

When I checked it with Profiler, I see this:

[image]

I intend to have only one session (meaning I can't have `sp_reset_connection` between the `INSERT INTO` and the `sp_executesql` commands - that is generated by the `SaveChanges` call)

So I tried the following:

```
      using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
      {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Schema1.View ([Key],[Value]) VALUES('Flag', '1')"); //session #1?
        //Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction,"INSERT INTO Schema1.View ([Key],[Value]) VALUES('Flag', '1')"); //session #1?
        base.SaveChanges(); //session #2? :(    
        scope.Complete();
      }
```

It didn't change anything.

I tried this also:

```
using (var tr = Database.Connection.BeginTransaction())
{
...
}
```

It throws an exception that the connection is closed.

What else should I try? Can I inject my `INSERT` into the `SaveChanges` code?

Comment: have you tried only one ExecuteSqlCommand passing a string with two inserts separated by semi colon?

Comment: @derloopkat I need to merge the INSERT string AND the SaveChanges into one `sp_executesql`. That's the tricky part...

Comment: Don't use this approach with "Command Execution" - very bad practice. Use StoredProcedures and pass params to it.

1 - if you get any mistake in your command STRING you can spend a lot of time to find it. Because it's just a STRING where you can write whatever you want.

2 - your case - You get runtime error and don't know where it comes from. When using SP you'll get errors like at compilation time within your "Select".

3 - If some changes come you need to change your STRING and Recompile all project. In DB you just Update your SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe wrapping the custom SQL command(s) and base `SaveChanges` call in database transaction is the correct way of doing what you need.

However, instead of using `BeginTransaction` method of the underlying `DbConnection` which also requires manually opening/closing it, you should use the [`Database.BeginTransaction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.begintransaction(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.BeginTransaction) method which will do the connection management for you:

```
using (var tr = Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    //...
    tr.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the key really was to use the Database object instead of the Connection :) It looks like it works okay.